# yolov5 not work well with fp16 model in cpp tflite

Tags: c++, yolo, tflite

I tried to run inference of yolov5 fp16 model in cpp. however, i found the type of the first layer is f32 but the size tf alloced is f16. [image: Input Tensor] Therefore, the data of the output tensor is a piece of mess.
link of the repository as following, which is a part of a android project.
[Link](https://github.com/aixiao0621/testyolov5/tree/master/app/src/main/cpp)
Here is how i load the model

```
    tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
    tflite::InterpreterBuilder builder(*mModel, resolver);
    builder(&mInterpreter);
    TfLiteStatus status = mInterpreter->AllocateTensors();
    _input = mInterpreter->inputs()[0];
    TfLiteIntArray *dims = mInterpreter->tensor(_input)->dims;
    _in_height = dims->data[1];
    _in_width = dims->data[2];
    _in_channels = dims->data[3];
    _in_type = mInterpreter->tensor(_input)->type;
    // yolo v5 input tensor which is kTFLiteFloat32
    _input_8 = mInterpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(_input);
```

And here is how i read from model

```
int _out = mInterpreter->outputs()[0];
    TfLiteIntArray *_out_dims = mInterpreter->tensor(_out)->dims;
    int _out_row   = _out_dims->data[1];   
    int _out_colum = _out_dims->data[2];   
    /*  model with
     *{
     *   "output_size": [1, 6300, 85],
     *   "input_size":  [320, 320]
     *}
     */
    TfLiteTensor *pOutputTensor = mInterpreter->tensor(mInterpreter->outputs()[0]);

    std::vector<std::vector<float>> predV{};
    tensor2Vector2d(pOutputTensor, predV, _out_row, _out_colum);

    std::vector<int> indices;
    std::vector<int> classIds;
    std::vector<float> confidences;
    std::vector<cv::Rect> boxes;

    nonMaximumSupprition(predV,
        boxes,
        confidences,
        classIds,
        indices,
        _out_row,
        _out_colum);

void FaceDetector::tensor2Vector2d(
    const TfLiteTensor *tensor,
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> &predV,
    const int row,
    const int col) {

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < row; i++){
        std::vector<float> _tem;

        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            float val_float = tensor->data.f[i * col + j];
            _tem.push_back(val_float);
        }
        predV.push_back(_tem);
    }
}

void FaceDetector::nonMaximumSupprition(std::vector<std::vector<float>>& predV,
    std::vector<cv::Rect> &boxes,
    std::vector<float> &confidences,
    std::vector<int> &classIds,
    std::vector<int> &indices,
    const int &row,
    const int &colum) {
    std::vector<cv::Rect> boxesNMS;
    std::vector<float> scores;
    double confidence;
    cv::Point classId;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        if (predV[i][4] > confThreshold){
            // height--> image.rows,  width--> image.cols;
            int left = (predV[i][0] - predV[i][2] / 2) * _img_width;
            int top = (predV[i][1] - predV[i][3] / 2) * _img_height;
            int w = predV[i][2] * _img_width;
            int h = predV[i][3] * _img_height;

            for (int j = 5; j < colum; j++)
            {
                // conf = obj_conf * cls_conf
                scores.push_back(predV[i][j] * predV[i][4]);
            }

            cv::minMaxLoc(
                scores,
                0,
                &confidence,
                0,
                &classId);

            if (confidence > confThreshold) {
                boxes.push_back(cv::Rect(left, top, w, h));
                confidences.push_back(confidence);
                classIds.push_back(classId.x % 80);
                boxesNMS.push_back(cv::Rect(left, top, w, h));
            }
        }
    }

    cv::dnn::NMSBoxes(
        boxesNMS,
        confidences,
        confThreshold,
        nmsThreshold,
        indices);
}
```

Some preprocessing

```
// copy img data to input tensor
template <typename T>
void FaceDetector::fill(T *in, cv::Mat &src) {
    int n = 0, nc = src.channels(), ne = src.elemSize();

    if (src.isContinuous()){
        memcpy(in, src.data, nc * src.cols * src.rows);
        return;
    }
    
    for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; ++x)
            for (int c = 0; c < nc; ++c)
                in[n++] = src.data[y * src.step + x * ne + c];
}

// preProcess
void FaceDetector::preProcess(cv::Mat &img) {
    cv::resize(
        img,
        img,
        cv::Size(
            _in_width,
            _in_height),
        cv::INTER_CUBIC);
        // convert img from uchar to f32 
        img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC3);
        // normalize
        img /= 255;
}
```

Tf get the input type from first layer so probably i cant change size which alloced by tflite?

I have tried turned the ptr of the input tensor to input tensor to int16 (i thought it is same as float16) and i convert the img to CV_16FC3 but not works.
I cant bear it XD,so suffering.

Comment: This question does not meet the site requirements for having a [mre] and being self-contained. You should edit your question with the actual code involved in loading the model

Comment: @Botje sry, i just add some relevant codes